# AccessViolationException with VST.NET and NAudio host application in C#

Tags: c#, casting, access-violation, naudio, vst

I'm trying to create a VSTstream class based on this thread: http://vstnet.codeplex.com/discussions/228692.

To record and playback the sound I'm using the `AsioOut` object that gives me available to `IntPtr[]` buffers type in the callback function `OnAudioAvailable()`.

To do this I created the `VSTstream` class, taking example from the thread linked, appropriately modified to process directly the `IntPtr[]` buffers.

During the various processes of casting, however, it gives me an error of "**AccessViolationException**", probably due to the casting wrong.

I'm testing the `VSTstream` class opening the *Jacobi.Vst.Samples.Delay.dll*

**EDIT:** The error occurs on this line:
`Marshal.Copy(sourceBuffer[1], rightBuf, 0, sampleCount/channels);`

Does anyone know what I did wrong? If you need additional information or code I'm available.

Thanks to all.

**OnAudioAvailable()**:

```
private void OnAudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
    {
        //No Effect
        for (int i = 0; i < e.InputBuffers.Length; i++)
        {
            MoveMemory(e.OutputBuffers[i], e.InputBuffers[i], e.SamplesPerBuffer * e.InputBuffers.Length * 2);
        }

        //Effect
        if (Parametri.effetto)
        {
            //Accendo i plugin
            for (int i = 0; i < plugins.Count; i++)
            {
                plugins[i].MainsChanged(true);
                plugins[i].StartProcess();
            }

            //Processo i sample
            vstStream.ProcessSample(e.OutputBuffers, 0, e.SamplesPerBuffer * e.InputBuffers.Length * 2, e.InputBuffers);

            //Spengo i plugin
            for (int i = 0; i < plugins.Count; i++)
            {
                plugins[i].StopProcess();
                plugins[i].MainsChanged(false);
            }
        }

        e.WrittenToOutputBuffers = true;
    }
```

**VSTstream class**:

```
class VSTstream
{
    public List<IVstPluginCommandStub> plugins;
    VstAudioBufferManager vstBufManIn, vstBufManOut;

    private VstAudioBuffer[] vstBufIn = null;
    private VstAudioBuffer[] vstBufOut = null;

    private int sampleRate, channels, blockSize;

    private float[] leftBuf, rightBuf;

    public VSTstream(int sampleRate, int channels, int blockSize, List<IVstPluginCommandStub> plugins)
    {
        this.plugins = plugins;
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.channels = channels;
        this.blockSize = blockSize;

        plugins[0].SetBlockSize(blockSize);
        plugins[0].SetSampleRate((float)sampleRate);

        vstBufManIn = new VstAudioBufferManager(channels, blockSize); //*channels
        vstBufManOut = new VstAudioBufferManager(channels, blockSize);

        //vstBufIn = vstBufManIn.ToArray();
        //vstBufOut = vstBufManOut.ToArray();
        vstBufIn = vstBufManIn.Cast<VstAudioBuffer>().ToArray();
        vstBufOut = vstBufManOut.Cast<VstAudioBuffer>().ToArray();

        leftBuf = new float[(blockSize * 4)/channels];
        rightBuf = new float[(blockSize * 4)/channels];
    }

    public int ProcessSample(IntPtr[] destBuffer, int offset, int sampleCount, IntPtr[] sourceBuffer)
    {
        //da IntPtr[L][R] a Lfloat[]+Rfloat[]
        Marshal.Copy(sourceBuffer[0], leftBuf, 0, sampleCount/channels);// (/channels)
        Marshal.Copy(sourceBuffer[1], rightBuf, 0, sampleCount/channels);

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (float* Lfloat = &leftBuf[0])
            {
                fixed (float* Rfloat = &rightBuf[0])
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount / channels; i++)
                    {
                        vstBufIn[0][i] = *(Lfloat + i);
                        vstBufIn[1][i] = *(Rfloat + i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Qui dovrà rimanere solo 'ProcessReplacing();'
        //plugins[0].MainsChanged(true);
        //plugins[0].StartProcess();
        plugins[0].ProcessReplacing(vstBufIn, vstBufOut);
        //plugins[0].StopProcess();
        //plugins[0].MainsChanged(false);

        unsafe
        {
            float* tmpBufL = ((IDirectBufferAccess32)vstBufOut[0]).Buffer;
            float* tmpBufR = ((IDirectBufferAccess32)vstBufOut[1]).Buffer;
            for (int i = 0; i < (sampleCount / channels); i++)
            {
                leftBuf[i] = *(tmpBufL + i);
                rightBuf[i] = *(tmpBufR + i);
            }
        }
        //da Lfloat[]+Rfloat[] a IntPtr[L][R]
        Marshal.Copy(leftBuf, 0, destBuffer[0], sampleCount/channels);
        Marshal.Copy(rightBuf, 0, destBuffer[1], sampleCount/channels);

        return sampleCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: With an exception like that you are very probably writing outside the boundary of your buffers. Any unsafe code? Check that. Make sure that buffers are as large as you think they should be...

Comment: Also, the first loop in the event handler uses the number of input buffers to index the output buffer array - I would not assume they are of equal size. 2) Do not switch the plugins on and off with each audio-available event. That would almost certainly lead to distorted audio output. Turn them on (and off) outside the callback/event.

Comment: I checked the size of the buffers and I noticed that I didn't have to divide by the `channels` in the `Copy` and the creation of float buffers. Removing that division, the error occurs in the first Copy instead in the second. The sizes are now this: `sourceBuffer[i]` =2048; `leftBuf` / `rightBuf` =2176; `sampleCount` =2048. Thanks for the advice about the on/off plugins.

Comment: I've given you the sizes of the buffers, but I don't know if they're right and the error is still there. I don't understand how to fix it, could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: This may help: https://vstnet.codeplex.com/discussions/544000